# Why Usenavigate in React app doesn't works?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

When I use navigate in React project(for login page), the page doesn't turn. I don't know Why. Is this code wrong?

```
fetch(postLoginURL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Who": "Admin",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id, passwd }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json(); 
        } else {
          throw new Error("Login Failed.");
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Login Success", data);

        return fetch(getMainURL, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Who": "Admin",
          },
        })
        navigate("/main");
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res)
        // window.location.href = '/main';  // navigate to /main
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Login failed: ", error);
      });
```

I import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom' at the top.
The login page appears, but it doesn't go through when I press the login button.

I expected Main page appears.

Comment: `return fetch(getMainURL, {` You're returning here, which means `navigate("/main");` is unreachable code. Did you mean to put `navigate("/main");` in the next .then? (where you did `// window.location.href = '/main';`)

Comment: I put <Navigate to="/main" /> in that location and error dissapeared, but page still doesn't change. Do you know why?

Comment: `<Navigate to="/main" />` only works if you return it from rendering a component. It won't work in a `.then` callback of a promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
return fetch(getMainURL, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Who: "Admin",
  },
});
navigate("/main");
```

The first line here has a return statement. As a result, the line `navigate("/main");` is unreachable and will never execute.

If you want to navigate before getting the main url, then swap these lines of code:

```
navigate("/main");
return fetch(getMainURL, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Who: "Admin",
  },
});
```

If you want to wait until you have the main url, then put `navigate("/main");` into the next `.then` block:

```
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Login Success", data);

    return fetch(getMainURL, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Who: "Admin",
      },
    });
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("res", res);
    navigate("/main");
  });
```